# Published Blazor application not using appsetting.Release.json

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor

I have published my Blazor application to local IIS using **Release** configuration settings.

I have an **appsettings.Release.json** file which is included in the published folder, but the values in **appsettings.Release.json** are not being used in the published application.

I have already added **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** value to **Release** for ApplicationHost.Config in the respective IIS Website.

[image]

How do I set the published application to "Release"?

Comment: Is there even appsettings.Release.json needed? Just checked one of my projects - there are appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json for debugging

Comment: @xakz I have published mine to local IIS with 'Release' configuration, hence that setting.

Answer (score 3):

Arghhh... In IIS I had configured my variable name with a space at the end...

`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`  was changed to `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and now all is working correctly.

[Facepalm]